# Move to end of the current word in Vim

Tags: vim

Usually I use **ea** to append something to a word; however, this doesn't work if the cursor is already in the last position of the word.

**ea** will cause the cursor to move to the end of the **next** word.

I'm interested to know whether there is any hotkey for moving to the end of **current** word even if the cursor is already in the last position of the word.

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just hit `a` then? You are already where you want to be, so why do you need a motion at all?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Because figuring out the exact cursor position is kind of distractive. Just knowing it is on the current word doesn't affect so much.

Comment: @VaughnCato Clever idea, thank you. Most of the time a word is preceded by a blank so this works even if the cursor is at the beginning of a word. But this requires 3 keystrokes. Although I can map it, does Vim have similear builtins? You see, Vim has 'append at the end of line", shouldn't it also provide 'append at the end of word"?

Comment: @cyker: I've honestly never run into that issue.  I think if I'm on the last character I automatically think of it as adding after the cursor instead of adding to the end of the word.

Comment: @cyker that's what customization and mappings are for :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can change the functionality of `e` if you desire. For example, you could put

```
nnoremap e he
```

in your ~/.vimrc. This maps `e` to `he` so that it works the way you want. However, you may find `e` useful and not want to make over it completely. You could use your `<leader>` key to add an alternate mapping.

```
nnoremap <leader>e he
```

So that you can use `\e` or `,e` (depending on your mapleader setting) to achieve the desired effect. I tend to agree with the others that it's better to become used to vim's standard single keys though. In general, use maps for longer commands that you regularly use.

There's no builtin command like the one you're suggesting, but there is regex `\>` for the end of a word.

Comment: Thank you, Conner. Personally I think w/b are enough to move between words. And 99% of the time my 'e' is followed by an 'a'. Well, bad habit.

Comment: Lol, remapping a two-character shortcut to a two-character shortcut

Comment: `he` fails if the cursor is at the beginning of a line and the word is one character long. Adding `onemore` to `virtualedit` and using `wge` works always, I believe.

Comment: To reiterate what @Stephan said in their answer, I would also advise against remapping the basic vim movement controls as they are the way they are for a reason.

Comment: @Olius you should turn your comment into an answer. It's the only correct one.

Answer (score 80):

- <kbd>h</kbd> moves you to the left by one position
- <kbd>e</kbd> moves you to the last letter of the word
- <kbd>a</kbd> lets you start editing one character ahead of the cursor

In your situation, it seems like you want a consistent way to append to a word, even if you're on the last letter. I'd switch to using <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> instead of <kbd>e</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

I advise against remapping the basic vim movement controls, they are the way they are for a reason.

Comment: wi prepends to the following word, doesnt append to the current word...

Comment: @JosephIreland try it yourself

Comment: `w` moves to the start of the next word, not the end of the current word. If i have "hello world" with cursor on "h", then `w` moves the cursor to the start of "world",  `i` starts editing at in front of "world", not at the end of "hello". I guess it would work if you had punctuation instead of a space.

Comment: i was testing on strings like "fish.dog.cat" instead of "fish dog cat", you're right

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.  It gives general information that isn't even relevant to the question, and provides a solution that doesn't work in any way whatsoever.

Comment: @Stephan Isn't this answer literally wrong? IMO, you should either edit it with the correct info or delete it.

Comment: @ClayBridges i have no idea why this answer was getting so many upvotes, fixed

Answer (score 5):

- Move to the end of the word: `e`
- Move to the beginning of the word: `b`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, and your "answer" clearly shows that you haven't read it at all.

Answer (score 4):

Try "**bea**". This will work regardless of where the cursor is within the word.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but can tell that your suggestion won't work as desired if the cursor is at the word's beginning.

Comment: `hea` will work instead

Answer (score 1):

## The motion `he`

is the answer that works in every single case: single-letter words, and cursor at any place in multiple-letter words.

PS: I added this answer because @Conner's, while indeed provides the correct answer, is polluted by off-topic recommendations and there needs to be concise and precise answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: But as @olius said, it doesn't work if the cursor is "at the beginning of a line and the word is one character long". However, olius's solution doesn't work if there's no other word after the current word

Answer (score 1):

## `wge` with `:se ve+=onemore`

1. [`w`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#w) moves to the beginning of the next word.
2. [`ge`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#ge) moves to the end of the previous word.

The problem is when we are at the last word in the buffer.
Then `w` moves to the end of that word *but not beyond*, so that `ge` then goes back to the end of the *previous* word.
To fix this, we can [add the `onemore` flag to `virtualedit`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27virtualedit%27):

```
:set virtualedit+=onemore
```

From [`:h onemore`](https://vimhelp.org/version7.txt.html#new-onemore):

```
Cursor past end of the line                             *new-onemore*
---------------------------

When the 'virtualedit' option contains "onemore" the cursor can move just past
the end of the line.  As if it's on top of the line break.

This makes some commands more consistent.  Previously the cursor was always
past the end of the line if the line was empty.  But it is far from Vi
compatible.  It may also break some plugins or Vim scripts.  Use with care!

The patch was provided by Mattias Flodin.
```