# Is there a Vim motion command that put cursor at beginning of current word?

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

Let's suppose I have the cursor located as depicted on next image

[image: cursor over text]

Pressing <kbd>b</kbd> in normal mode I can go to the start of the word.

[image]

Great!

If I move cursor to *1* like

[image]

and press <kbd>b</kbd> we have

[image]

Question:

Is there a motion command to move cursor to start of the word so that if the word is one character long remains at the initial position? In my example, the cursor should stay at *1*.

I'm looking this motion command to implement a Macro that in some of the steps move cursor to the start of a word, with words sometimes having just one character.

Comment: "*if the word is one character long remains at the initial position*" So if you run the command next time the cursor wouldn't move? And yet another time — still doesn't?

Comment: Such command doesn't exist, macro is impossible, and a function could be possible but quite hard to debug in all situations. Forget it.

Comment: try this: `"_yiw`

Comment: @user938271 That's an awesome solution, you should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 13):

Simplest solution I  have found for this is just `wb` which works wherever your cursor is on the word, and for single character and multi character words.

Source is reddit user 'happysri' from this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1xzfjy/go_to_start_of_current_word_if_not_already_there/

Comment: Surreal to search for a quick solution to a problem and find an answer quoting my own reddit comment from 8 years ago :D

Comment: Thank you Sri for providing the solution in the first place.

Comment: `lb` also works pefectly for all cases.

Comment: `lb` fails in at least one case that quickly comes to mind: lines with only one word of one character length. Both methods actually fail if this happens to be the very last line of the file.

Answer (score 3):

I've found this answer [Move to end of the current word in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488348/move-to-end-of-the-current-word-in-vim) that is somehow similar to my problem...

Applying the idea shown there, I should always move one character forward <kbd>l</kbd> and then move at the beginning of the word with <kbd>b</kbd>. That works and it is consistent for words of different sizes.

Comment: Does it work with 1-character words? I don't believe it does. Actually I don't believe it works if you execute it 2 times in a row.

Comment: You are right, It does not work if executed twice....but as a workaround, works in the sense that move the cursor to the start of the word consistently ....

Comment: See my answer for this, `wb` avoids any issues with double execution or 1 character words.

Comment: I don't really understand what you all saying, `lb` works perfectly on my end even on 1 letter words and even twice in a row using `lblb` when the cursor on the word "1" sends me back to "1" correctly (just as `wbwb` does, and even `bwbw`)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is such a motion (please, anyone, correct me if I'm wrong)

But you can achieve that with a search:

```
:call search('\<', 'bc')
```

- `\<` matches the beginning of a word

---

- The `b` stands for backwards
- The `c` is to accept matches under the cursor